# Lift Kleisli arrow into IO?

Tags: haskell, io, arrows, lifting, kleisli

If I have the following two Kleisli arrows:

```
stdoutProcessA :: Kleisli Maybe String (IO String)
writeToFileA :: Kleisli Maybe (FilePath, String) (IO ())
```

I would like to be able to write someting like:

```
compile = proc src -> do
    output <- stdoutProcessA -< "..."
    writeToFileA -< ("...", output)
    ...
```

which of course doesn't work, because `String` doesn't match with `IO String`. On the other hand, it is possible to define both `stdoutProcessA` and `writeToFileA` to be of type `Kleisli IO ...`, but then I wouldn't be able to compose them with arrows of type `Kleisli Maybe ...`, which I need for other things.

I am not very experienced with arrows yet, so I'm probably missing something obvious. How would one go about doing the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These arrows don't make much sense to me:

```
stdoutProcessA :: Kleisli Maybe String (IO String)
writeToFileA :: Kleisli Maybe (FilePath, String) (IO ())
```

They represent functions with result `Maybe (IO a)`, when you probably meant `IO (Maybe a)`. The latter type represents `IO` actions which may fail, while in the former the failure or success cannot depend on the `IO` at all.

The correct way to combine `IO` and `Maybe` is to use the `MaybeT` monad transformer, like so:

```
stdoutProcessA :: Kleisli (MaybeT IO) String String
writeToFileA :: Kleisli (MaybeT IO) (FilePath, String) ()
```

If you write your other arrows as `Monad m => Kleisli (MaybeT m) a b`, they should compose nicely with these ones without any lifting. Alternatively, you can use

```
lift' :: Monad m => Kleisli Maybe a b -> Kleisli (MaybeT m) a b
lift' (Kleisli f) = Kleisli $ \x -> MaybeT (return $ f x)
```

to lift your existing `Kleisli Maybe` arrows to `Kleisli (MaybeT IO)` where needed.

Comment: Yes, it would actually make much more sense for them to be just of type `Kleisli IO String String` and `Kleisli IO (FilePath, String) ()` but then I wouldn't be able to combine them with other arrows of type `Kleisli Maybe` - is there a way to combine Kleise arrows in different monads?